# Open popup when textbox has keyboard focus and close via "staysopen = false" property

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, popup

As mentioned in the title, I want the popup to show, when the textbox gains keyboard focus, but then close when the user clicks outside of the popup (which is done via staysopen = false).

As you can see by the code below, I have bound the `IsOpen` property to the ExampeTextBox's `IsKeyboardFocused` property. This works for opening the popup, but prevents me from interacting with the popup, as I call `Keyboard.ClearFocus();` in a click event that gets called when the user clicks anywhere on the window. This means that clicking anywhere outside of the textbox causes `Keyboard.ClearFocus()` to fire, causing the textbox to lose keyboard focus.

If I set `StaysOpen = false` and then set `IsOpen` programmatically via `Popup.IsOpen = true;` it causes the properties `IsOpen` and `StaysOpen` to conflict and the popup won't show up at all.

```
           <Popup
           x:Name="ExamplePopup"
           Placement="Bottom"
           PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=ExampleTextBox}"
           IsOpen="{Binding ElementName=ExampleTextBox, Path=IsKeyboardFocused, Mode=OneWay}">...</Popup>
```

[Here is a screen recording of my problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3W62K.jpg)

Any help is much appreciated thanks.

Comment: why not use an autocomplete textbox instead of normal textbox. It appears as if you want to show search suggestions in your popup

Comment: what are you doing by using a popup exactly?

Answer (score 1):

You can bind `IsOpen` to a `boolean` property which makes your `popup` visible or not.

```
<Popup
           x:Name="ExamplePopup" StaysOpen="True"
           Placement="Bottom"
           PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=ExampleTextBox}"
           IsOpen="{Binding IsNeedToOpen}">
    </Popup>
```

When your `textbox` gets `focus` set the `property` value `true` and when you need close popup set the `property` value `false`. Make sure you implement **`INotifyPropertyChanged`** `interface` and set `DataContext`.

```
  private bool _IsNeedToOpen = false;
    public bool IsNeedToOpen
    {
        get { return _IsNeedToOpen; }
        set
        {
            if (_IsNeedToOpen == value) { return; }
            _IsNeedToOpen = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsNeedToOpen");
        }
    }
    private void TextBox_GotKeyboardFocus(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        IsNeedToOpen = true;
    }
```